# Why sometimes my_arc_mutex.clone() will be freed before finishing using it?

Tags: rust

I got this error:

```
   --> src/client.rs:189:22
    |
189 |         let client = client.clone().lock().unwrap();
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
    |                      |
    |                      creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
```

on this function that is too big for me to post a minimum reproducible example:

```
async fn send_and_expect<T: OnEvent<T>>(
        client: Arc<Mutex<Self>>,
        request: rtsp_types::Message<Body>,
        unauthorized_retry: i32,
    ) -> std::result::Result<rtsp_types::Response<Body>, ClientActionError>
    where
        RtspMachine: OnEvent<T>,
        T: From<Response>,
    {
        let expected_cseq = client_parse_cseq(&request)?;
        let mut client = client.lock().unwrap();
```

If I simply not clone, that is, do `let mut client = client.lock().unwrap();`, it compiles. But I was wondering why `clone()` makes this error happen.

I tried to reproduce the problem to post here:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
fn main() {
    let a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    a.clone().lock().unwrap();
}
```

but this compiles ok.

What is wrong? Why would `client.clone()` sometimes be freed before finishing using it but sometimes not?

Comment: Your `main()` example gives the same error if you try to *use* the result: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6750204cec244759657b63dc2ebd4e94)

Comment: @kmdreko why simply Rust doesn't make the cloned value live until the end of the line?

Comment: It does live until the end of the line. However, the result is a `MutexGuard` which holds a *reference* to the inner value of the `Mutex`, and thus requires it to live longer.

Comment: @kmdreko doesn't `let b = ` makes the reference be bound to `b`? I'm lost.

Comment: This code is equivalent to `let b = ({ let tmp2 = ({ let tmp1 = a.clone(); tmp1 }).lock(); tmp2 }).unwrap();`. The `let b = ` binds `tmp2` to `b`, but `tmp1` is dropped even though `b` refers to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your short example is too short, because it never binds the `unwrap`ped MutexGuard. To reproduce the error, we need to add a binding ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fa552283182cedf7d8989c3044e93989)):

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    let _b = a.clone().lock().unwrap();
}
```

`rustc` now yells at use righteously:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:5:13
  |
5 |     let _b = a.clone().lock().unwrap();
  |              ^^^^^^^^^                - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |              |
  |              creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
6 | }
  | - borrow might be used here, when `_b` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `MutexGuard`
  |
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

So why does the borrow checker yell at us? Remember that [`Mutex::lock(&self)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.lock) takes a reference to the `Mutex`. This reference stems from `Arc`. However, the `clone`d variant only lives till the end of the statement: there is no binding to `a.clone()`, and it passes away into oblivion at the semicolon.

The easy fix is to bind `a.clone()`. Usually, you would reuse the same identifier, as in [Rust's `Arc` example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#examples) ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0fcf111ca73af80680338ec0c9669d96)):

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    let a = a.clone();
    let _b = a.lock().unwrap();
}
```

While this might seem strange in a single `main` function, it's much more common when `move`ing values into closures.

"Now hold on", you might say. "This is a shared reference, why can't I just keep using it? There's still `a` in the same scope!" While this *could* be true, it's also a trap. If the `.clone().lock()` line were to compile, then we could create a use-after-free error:

```rust
let a = Arc::new(Mutx::new(0));
let b = a.clone().lock().unwrap(); // reference counter increased and decreased by 1
drop(a);                           // reference counter -> 0: value gets freed                       
*b = 10;                           // whoops!
```